# I want to use component annotation in my spring core program but in config.xml there is rising error while using tag 'context:component-scan'

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zW8s.png)# why am I not able to use this context:component-scan tag as I am following a youtuber's spring tutorial The error showing is: "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'."

I have a class Student and a class test in which I am using @component so that I have not to make bean in traditional way.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjxVC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8p56.png)

Comment: Don't use images of code (or worse links to images of code). Include the code surrounded with code tags in your question.